# Linux Vim delete lines that don't contain abc or xyz

Tags: linux, vim, text, formatting

In Vim there is :v for excluding lines for a delete

```
:v/abc/d
```

to delete all lines that do not have abc in them. Which is fine but what if I want to delete everything that doesn't contain abc OR xyz?

Comment: the bar worked thank you, the :he documentation wasn't 100% clear though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
:v/\(abc\)\|\(xyz\)/d
```

Comment: No need to do grouping, or do I miss anything?

Comment: this worked perfectly although I have no idea how it works, would you recommend somewhere I can read up a bit on how this is working?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, it looks like you were using brackets and escaping them with the '\' so I should be able to use      :v/abc\|xyz/d

Comment: @Marth I had a look at :help and it gave me a good idea but it was a bit unclear so it's nice to see it in action like William Pursell showed, thanks though

Comment: This was perfect. I understand everything except the `:v` and `/d` .